# How do I specify the stream length when deserializing protocol buffers using protobuf-net?

Tags: tcp, stream, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am trying to use Protocol Buffers to send an integer from a server to a client over a TCP connection. I believe that my server is writing stuff to the stream, but my code pauses indefinitely when the client tries to deserialize from a network stream. My gut is telling me that the client doesn't know the length of the stream so it doesn't know when the reading is complete, but the Deserialize method doesn't have an input for length so I'm not sure how to implement this. Below is the code for my proto definition, server, and client.

PROTO DEFINITION

```
Public Class Proto
<ProtoContract()>
Public Class TCP
    <ProtoMember(1)>
    Public Property Command As Integer

End Class
End Class
```

SERVER CODE

```
    Dim commandStuff As New Proto.TCP
    Console.WriteLine("Enter command number")
    commandStuff.Command = Console.ReadLine()


    Dim myIP As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("my address")
    Dim myServer As New TcpListener(myIP, 800)
    myServer.Start() 'starts listening,
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection")
    Dim myClient As TcpClient = myServer.AcceptTcpClient() 'Accepts client,  pauses program until finds a client
    Console.WriteLine("Connected")

    Dim myStream As NetworkStream = myClient.GetStream
    ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(Of Proto.TCP)(myStream, commandStuff) 'write the instance commandStuff to the stream myStream

    Console.WriteLine("Stuff has been written")
    Console.ReadLine()
```

This code runs completely without any issues

CLIENT CODE

```
    Dim IP As IPAddress
    IP = IPAddress.Parse("my address")
    Dim myClient As New TcpClient
    myClient.Connect(IP, 800)
    Console.WriteLine("Connected")

    Dim myStream As NetworkStream

    myStream = myClient.GetStream
    Console.WriteLine("Stream created")

    Dim ReceivedCommand As New Proto.TCP

    ReceivedCommand = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize(Of Proto.TCP)(myStream)

    Console.WriteLine("Stream deserialized")
    Dim Command As Integer
    Command = ReceivedCommand.Command
    Console.WriteLine(Command)
    Console.ReadLine()
```

This code gets stuck at `ReceivedCommand = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize(Of Proto.TCP)(myStream)`

The format for the deserialization is `Deserialize(Of T)(source As System.IO.Stream)`, with the explanation as "Creates a new instance from a protocol-buffer stream"

I realized that there is a method that allows you to serialize and deserialize with a length prefix, appropriately named "SerializeWithLengthPrefix"

My one concern is that in the future I won't be writing the server code, and I believe the server code will be in C++, which may or may not have the option for a prefixed length.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that there is a method that allows you to serialize and deserialize with a length prefix, appropriately named "SerializeWithLengthPrefix"

My one concern is that in the future I won't be writing the server code, and I believe the server code will be in C++, which may or may not have the option for a prefixed length.